# What does the inverted comma mean in set theory?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

What does the inverted comma mean in set theory?

I have used it, and I don't know what it means.

Here is an example:  $(X ∪ X')$

Comment: It means complement; $X’$ is the set of elements not in $X$

Comment: I agree with J.W. Tanner that it most likely means complement. I would like to add the caveat that I've seen multiple notations for complement, (like $X^{c}$), and I have seen different meanings for $X'$, so context matters. Ideally the author will clarify his/her notation when it is first introduced.

Comment: I agree it could mean other things in other contexts; e.g., set of limit points in topology

Comment: In Portugal, usually, $X'$ is the set of $X$ cluster points.

Comment: it really depends on the context: the best way is to find the notation definition in the book/notes you are reading

Comment: Come to think of it, I am pretty sure the questions I am looking at mean not in X. I haven't looked at this stuff in a while. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments of others and me, in set theory, $X'$ most commonly denotes the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of set $X$, i.e., the set of elements not in $X$.  For example, working in the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,...\},$ the complement of the set of primes is the set containing composites and $1$.  But $X'$ could mean other things in other contexts, and there are other notations used for set complement, so the author should define the symbol before using it.

Comment: In set theory nobody uses $X'$ (nor $X^c$) to denote the complement of $X$.

Comment: @Jonathan Really?  Do you have a citation for that?  What notation *is* used?

Comment: Usually we write $Y \setminus X$. I have never seen $X'$ used in set theoretical literature, and only rarely $X^c$. But I am aware that it is very common in other fields.